# Does Windows 11 support auto-adaptive resolution when opening a window of a remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

When accessing a remote desktop with the remote desktop tool that comes with Windows 11, how do I get the remote desktop window to adjust its resolution based on the window size?

[image: integrated remote desktop tool]

The problem I'm currently facing: The remote desktop's taskbar only shows when the remote window is maximized. But in that case, my own desktop's taskbar is missing. How can both taskbars coexist?

[image: the remote desktop's taskbar is hidden]

If the integrated tool that comes with Windows doesn't work, is there any other tool that can give me what I want?